# How to fetch data from firebase in the form of ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In this format i have databse in firebase.I have to display all the departments in the form of array list like Director,sports.

[image: firebase]

```
mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
 mdatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Department";
mdatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> Department = (ArrayList<String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
         DepartmentLIST=Department.toArray(new String[Department.size()]);

    }
   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
       Toast.makeText(CheckUpdate.this,databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

  });

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,DepartmentLIST));
```

}

This is my code i have used for it. But it gives NullValue.

Answer (score 1):

`(ArrayList<String>) dataSnapshot.getValue()` isn't correct.

I think you are looking for `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`, and / or `dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class)`.

Note: Firebase-UI library could help you here.